# Ctype - Could not find DLL dependencies

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to use already existing C library "IMSApiCLib.dll" to communicate with external program.
Problem is that this library is using some Java sub-libraries. Before using this library I need to set "Java" path to correct (actual) folder (tested with Tester.exe provided with DLL)

So I have BAT file which prepare it and run Python script itself

```
cd C:\API\imsapi-clib-9.10.00-7-windows64\
set PATH=.;.\java\jre\bin;.\java\jre\bin\server;%PATH%
python C:\API\imsapi-clib-9.10.00-7-windows64\Connection.py
```

**Connection.py:**

```
DllPath = r"C:\API\imsapi-clib-9.10.00-7-windows64\IMSApiCLib.dll"
imsapi_clib= ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(DllPath)
```

> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module
> 'C:\API\imsapi-clib-9.10.00-7-windows64\IMSApiCLib.dll' (**or one of
> its dependencies**). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

It seems that added new JAVA path is not used when using `ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary()`

Any tips?

Comment: You may try the tool [dependency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see the dependencies of your dll.

Comment: calling  "imsapi_clib= ctypes.WinDLL(DllPath, winmode=1)" seems to solve my issue

Comment: That just tells Windows not to load dependencies and skip calling DllMain.  Once you call an API that references a dependency, or if there is initialization in DllMain that was skipped, you could have problems.